# Тег <pre>. Неправильное отображение

Tags: html

Есть такой код внутри тега pre`

```
$config = [
'path'       => 'files/images/captcha',
'text'       => 'My some text',
'expiration' => 60,
'font'       => 'app/fonts/simple.ttf',
'angle'      => 0,
'width'      => 300,
'height'     => 50,
'fontSize'   => 18,
'colors' => [
    'text'       => [255, 200, 168],
    'background' => [255, 255, 255]
    ]
];
```

Должно ведь в браузере все так же отобразиться? Но получаю вот что (http://s013.radikal.ru/i324/1508/1b/c95f5ad8d087.png)
То есть пробелы как-то странно выводятся. Можно ли как-то исправить что бы все ровно выводилось?

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4RQb.png
```

Comment: что имеено не так - отступы?

Comment: Да там шрифт не моноширинный. Предлагаю в браузере посмотреть на свойства css элемента pre.

Comment: Visman, спасибо! Действительно, я не указал шрифты для pre

Answer (score 1):

http://htmlbook.ru/html/pre - прочтите про тег . Думаю Вам бужет полезно. Все остальные стили этого тега Вы можете задать html атрибутами или определить его стиль в файле .css